# Clear Current Session while Back Navigation in browser

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net application. How can I **clear current session**, if user perform a back navigation in his browser?

Comment: What's your objective with that? Maybe there are more realistic approaches :)

Comment: Ignoring for a moment how you want to _respond_ to the back button (that is, clearing the session), how do you plan to _detect_ that the back button has been pressed?  Historically this tends to be very difficult and unreliable.  In general HTTP is a simple request/response system.  The browser simply sends requests to your server.  How can you tell the difference between the browser sending a request because the user pressed the back button, or clicked a link to that same page, or manually typed in the address for that page, etc.?

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the session by (probably what you want):

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Or clear all values in the session by:

```
Session.Clear();
```

Comment: From which event Can i Call Session.Abandon(). How can I know back navigation is occured?

Comment: It's not your question. However there is no event. You have to build something custom. Detecting a back browser button is smell, which means there is something wrong with your code. For example you save something twice in the database, which indicates that you do a save action in your database without forcing the user to do a get (redirect).

Comment: There is no back navigation event. The only way to capture this would be to use the javascript method OnUnload() and that will capture when the client navigates away from the page, regardless of where they're going.

Comment: @peter You should provide a complete solution. Here main challenge to identify back button clicked.